# Saving form variables onchange with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to save form data into `$_SESSION` variables with ajax, but I can't seem to run the onchange event properly or send the variable.

The form length varies, so I've tried to use dynamic variables.

```
<script>
    function orderValues(boxValue){
        $.post("/ajaxConnect.php",{value: $("qty_" + boxValue).val()}, 
        function( result ) {
            console.log('value saved');
        });
    }
</script>

<php
    echo "<div id=\"prodBox\">QTY: <input name=\"qty_".rawurldecode($item->LINE)."\" value=\"" . $_SESSION['box_']['qty_'.rawurldecode($item->LINE)] . "\" type=\"number\" onchange=\"orderValues(this.value)\"/></div>";
?>
```

ajaxConnect:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['box_']['value'] = $_POST["value"];
?>
```

The end goal is for input values to be saved to `$_SESSION['box_']['qty_LINE']` whenever the value is changed.

If I set the `$_SESSION` value manually I can get it to show, but not through ajax.

Cheers for any help.

Comment: In JQuery, use `#` for id mapping and in php get your array indexes straight.

Comment: You will be able to access the session values in other pages of site or once you reload the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a better practice to use jquery to do the event bindings instead of using attributes like `onchange`, and you also need to make sure you get the right values to send to your server, you need both the line name and the value.

So remove the `onchange` attribute:

```
<php
    echo "<div id=\"prodBox\">QTY: <input name=\"qty_".rawurldecode($item->LINE)."\" value=\"" . $_SESSION['box_']['qty_'.rawurldecode($item->LINE)] . "\" type=\"number\" /></div>";
?>
```

And use this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#prodBox input').change(function(){
        $.post("/ajaxConnect.php",{line: this.name, value: this.value}, 
        function( result ) {
            console.log('value saved');
        });
    });
});
```

Finally, update your `ajaxConnect` file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $line = isset($_POST["line"]) ? $_POST["line"] : '';
    $value = isset($_POST["value"]) ? $_POST["value"] : '';
    $_SESSION['box_'][$line] = $value;
?>
```

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly once I remembered to put in the jQuery ref.